# Использование метода Yii::t() в twig шаблонах.

Tags: шаблоны, twig, yii

Подключил к `Yii` фреймворку `Twig` шаблонизатор. Интересует вопрос: как можно воспользоваться методом `Yii::t()` в `twig` шаблонах?
То есть, чтобы было как - то так:

```
{{Yii.t('main', 'some_text')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для интернационализации шаблонов самым правильным решением было бы воспользоваться расширением [i18n](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html).

При наличии расширения gettext Yii'шный класс для интернационализации, на мой взгляд, совершенно бесполезен. Поскольку gettext и быстрее, и удобнее, и предоставляет все необходимые утилиты для парсинга токенов для дальнешего перевода.

Answer (score 0):

Так а что мешает туда вставить эту строчку и проверить?

Или что-то не получается? Тогда что конкретно?

Так и написать туда

```
Yii::t('main', 'hashcode')
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы этим методом воспользоваться, его надо передать шаблонизатору. Вот как ему передать этот метод, меня и интересует. )

Comment: Так. Вроде как решил вопрос, передав в шаблонизатор проинициализированный класс Yii. То есть:  

    $yii=new Yii();
    $this->_twig->addGlobal('Yii', $yii);    
И в Твиге уже собственно и используем:

    {{Yii.t('main','main page')}}    
Но меня интересует вопрос, корректно ли так делать.

Comment: Ну если честно, то скорее всего некорректно. Возможно и ошибаюсь, но 

>YII.t() Translates a message to the specified language. 

Не уверен что такой подход будет правильным.